# background-clip property makes the whole div disappear

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the full stop in this heading to be black **and** on the same line as the last word. So far I manage to achieve one or the other.

[top: what I'm after Below: what it displays so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUBzJ.png)

```
<style>

.HeroTitle {
  font-size: 56px;
  letter-spacing: -2.5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.HeroTitle p {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(69,85,145,1) 0%, rgba(26,188,195,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.HeroTitle a {
  color: black !important;
}

</style>

<div class="HeroTitle" >

Simplify the complexity of
<p>delivering your next service<a>.</a></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`. Simply use `color:transparent`

```css
.HeroTitle {
  font-size: 56px;
  letter-spacing: -2.5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.HeroTitle p {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(69,85,145,1) 0%, rgba(26,188,195,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color:transparent;
}

.HeroTitle span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="HeroTitle" >

Simplify the complexity of
<p>delivering your next service<span>.</span></p>

</div>
```

Comment: If you absolutely have to use the `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`,  you can also place the same `-webkit-text-fill-color: black;` in your `.HeroTitle a` style. However I don't really see a reason why you'd have to.